# WPF Can't Find some Fonts

Tags: wpf, fonts

Why is it that `Media.Fonts` can't find `"Arial Rounded MT Bold"`?

```
foreach (var f in System.Windows.Media.Fonts.SystemFontFamilies)
{
    if (f.Source == "Arial Rounded MT Bold")
    {
        var x = "Not Found";
    }
}

var fc = new System.Drawing.Text.InstalledFontCollection();
foreach (var fd in fc.Families)
{
    if (fd.Name == "Arial Rounded MT Bold")
    {
        var x = "Found";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check in your system's Windows folder. Do u have "Arial Rounded MT Bold" font installed on your system?? You might not have the font installed on your system.. That might be the only issue for not finding it..

Ok, i got it in first loop you are looping through System Font families and for "Arial Rounded MT Bold" its font family is "Arial Rounded MT". You can check about its specification here - http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=918

So, if you update your code like this -

```
foreach (var f in System.Windows.Media.Fonts.SystemFontFamilies)
{
      if (f.Source == "Arial Rounded MT")
      {
         var x = "Found";
      }
}
```

You will get that font which you are looking for..

Comment: Yes I do have it installed. I can not only browse to it but also the second foreach loop in the code sample will find the font.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Hope this is what you are asking for if i get you right.

Comment: In summary - Would your answer be SystemFontFamilies has a different name than InstalledFontCollection for Arial Rounded MT? InstalledFontCollection appends "BOLD" to the end? This is what I suspected and makes it difficult to convert winform (System.Drawing) fonts to WPF(System.Windows.Media) fonts.

Comment: Yeah SystemFontFamilies only contains family names like if you check in these two collections - SystemFontFamilies will have only one value for "Arial" font family whereas in InstalledFontCollection will have three different values namely - "Arial", "Arial Narrow", "Arial Black". SystemFontFamilies only contains only font families to be precise.